# Popup in Silverlight 5 with Chrome

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, null, popup

I've got an irritating problem. I want to open a popup window in a standard way:

`System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPopupWindowOptions options =
new System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPopupWindowOptions();
// Setting the options...`

var x = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.PopupWindow(MyPath, "_blank", options);

It works perfectly well in FF and IE, but I observe a strange behavior in Chrome. The popup actually OPENS, but I've got `null` in `x`. And yes, I set
`allowHtmlPopupWindow` to `true`.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance!